# Generate random new random string if exist on sql

Tags: php, sql

I have a question, how can I create a random string in PHP and check on a SQL if the string exist, if exist, create a new one, but if it doesnt exist use it

I have this code to create the random string:

```
$original_string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$random_string = get_random_string($original_string, 14);
echo $random_string;
```

And the MySQL I would like to check if the random string is already been use is this one:

```
CREATE TABLE `en_videos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` text,
  `code` text,
  `description` text,
  `hits` int(11) default NULL,
  `program` int(11) default NULL,
  `lenght` int(11) default NULL,
  `hd` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
  `subtitles` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
  `type` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I would like to check if the random string exists on the **code** field

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$original_string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$random_string = '';

do {
    $random_string = get_random_string($original_string, 14);
} while ($mysqli->query('SELECT 1 FROM `en_videos`
             WHERE `code` = "' . $random_string . '"')->fetch_row());

echo $random_string;
```

This assume you're using the `mysqli` library. If not, use whatever fetches rows as your condition handler.

Assuming you're using the `mysql_*` functions (in which case, I suggest you look into other [mysql libraries](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)):

```
$original_string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$random_string = '';

do {
    $random_string = get_random_string($original_string, 14);
} while ($mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT 1 FROM `en_videos`
             WHERE `code` = "' . $random_string . '"')));

echo $random_string;
```

Comment: I try using the code, and didnt work :(
http://www.enteratenorte.com/admon/test.php

Comment: Try the second example (assuming you're using `mysql_*`)

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as found_num
from en_videos
where `code` = '$random_string'
```

returns `0` if the string was not found and `> 0` if it was.